# In Xcode 11, the tab that has the properties of the UI Elements is missing

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode-storyboard

When we work with the storyboard, there's a tab that shows up on the left that details the various UI components that are present in the respective ViewController. That seems to have disappeared and I've tried everything under the sun.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ3yj.jpg)

Comment: When adding images here, please (a) use the official image provider, and (b) please render them inline, so people do not have to go to another website to see what you wish to show them. The official image provider is more resilient (images can't be deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small button in left of View as iPhone 11 pro. Use this button to toggle the detailed view.